# highcharts simple moving average day, weekly, monthly

Tags: highcharts, moving-average, candlestick-chart

I want to use a button to make the candlestick visible by day, week, and month, but I want the moving average line to not change automatically (only the day moving average line).

```
_chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'ohlc',
        id: 'aapl',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: data
    }, {
        type: 'sma',
        linkedTo: 'aapl'
    }, {
        type: 'sma',
        linkedTo: 'aapl',
        params: {
            period: 50
        }
    }]
  });
  });
 change(function() {

    var unit = $(this).val();
    console.log(123123);

    _chart.series.forEach(function(ser) {
        ser.update({
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [ [unit, [1]] ]
            }
        }, false);
    });

    console.log(unit);
    _chart.redraw(unit);
    console.log(_chart);
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the problem. Can you explain it on this example?: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tywzukj4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highcharts moving average day, week, month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740298/highcharts-moving-average-day-week-month)